# sematext logagent debugging patterns

Tags: debugging, logging

I have installed sematext logagent https://sematext.github.io/logagent-js/installation/
Configured it to output to elasticsearch and all is good but one thing which i spent this all day trying to do.
There is 0, null, none information on how to debug parsers. I start logagent with "logagent --config logagent.yml -v -j", yml file bellow

```
options:
  printStats: 30
  # don't write parsed logs to stdout
  suppress: false
  # Enable/disable GeoIP lookups
  # Startup of logagent might be slower, when downloading the GeoIP database
  geoipEnabled: false
  # Directory to store Logagent status nad temporary files
  diskBufferDir: ./tmp

input:
  files:
      - '/var/log/messages'
      - '/var/log/test'

patterns:
  sourceName: !!js/regexp /test/
  match:
    - type: mysyslog
      regex: !!js/regexp /([a-z]){2}(.*)/
      fields: [message,severity]
      dateFormat: MMM DD HH:mm:ss

output:
  elasticsearch:.
    module: elasticsearch
    url: http://host:9200
    index: mysyslog
  stdout: yaml # use 'pretty' for pretty json and 'ldjson' for line delimited json (default)
```

I would expect (based on the scares documentation) that this would split each line of test file into 2, example 'ggff', 'gg' would be message, 'ff' would be severity, but all i can see in my kibana is that 'ggff' is a message and severity is defaulted (?) to info. The problem is, i dont know where the problem is. Does it skip my pattern, does match in my pattern fail ? any help would be VERY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Setting 'debug: true' in patterns.yml prints detailed info about matched patterns.
https://github.com/sematext/logagent-js/blob/master/patterns.yml#L36
Watch Logagent issue #69 (https://github.com/sematext/logagent-js/issues/69) for additional improvements.

The docs moved to http://sematext.com/docs/logagent/ . I recommend www.regex101.com to test regular expressions (please use JavaScript regex syntax).

Examples of Syslog messages in /var/log are in the default pattern library: 
https://github.com/sematext/logagent-js/blob/master/patterns.yml#L498